# Firebase Messaging Get Cloud Function Name

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 different cloud functions that send a notification to the device. one is sendNewChatMessageNotification and the other one is sendNewFriendRequestNotification.

How can I get the function name that triggered the onMessage method of the firebaseMessaging instance? because I want to show different messages for the different cloud functions.

```
final firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
   firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((tokenVal) {
     fcmToken = tokenVal;
    
   firebaseMessaging.configure(

     onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

     // -----> how can I get the cloudFunctionName ??


     if(cloudFunctionName == "sendNewFriendRequestNotification"){
       //show friend request notification
     }else if(cloudFunctionName == "sendNewChatMessageNotification"){
      //show new chat message notification
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to code your function to send that string value in the payload of the message.  It will not be sent automatically.